# Replace in files AND count number of replacements?

Tags: command-line, unix

I use the following line to replace a string in files:

```
ag -Q -l "$1" | xargs sed -i '' "s/$1/$2/g"
```

`ag` is the_silver_searcher, of course.

How can I also count the number of files that were affected by this change?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tee` in the pipe line and create a temporary file, then run `wc -l` to count the number of files (lines).

```
ag -Q -l "$1" | tee -a /tmp/num | xargs sed -i '' "s/$1/$2/g"; wc -l /tmp/num; rm /tmp/num
```

Comment: nice, but I would really avoid creating temp files